# Delete Row + Move up based on partial text match in a Column

Tags: vba, if-statement, delete-row

I want a macro to **delete** any row that **contains** `general` in Column A and move up (to eliminate a blank row).

I have been attempting this but have been unsuccessful:

```
Sub format()
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20").Value = "general" Then
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToUp 
End If
End Sub
```

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: I would guess that you don't have a selection yet. That's why you can't delete the selection. Try selecting first ;-)

Comment: Also you can't compare a whole range with a value. You have to either loop through each cell in A1:A20 or use autofilter or find.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using AutoFilter, which not require a loop.

```
Sub x()

Dim rData As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
Range("A1:E1").Value = Array(1, 2, 3, 4,5) 'amend to how many columns you have

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*General*"
    With .AutoFilter.Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rData Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            rData.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Rows(1).Delete
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! it Works! its just not deleting the first 2 rows of data which does contain `general`...

Comment: Forgot to mention that autofilter does require a header row. Just insert a row at the top and put anything in it, and can delete at the end. Could do that in the code too.

Comment: If you can add that in the code for me that would be great please and thanks! i`m truly a beginner at this.

Comment: truly appreciate your help!